# nextauth file imported EmailProvider is not being used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to use nextauth for authentication. I'm trying to import EmailProvider from nextauth/providers. when I use it in Nextauth providers object it does not refer to EmailProvider i've imported?

code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { EmailProvider } from "next-auth/providers";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        EmailProvider({
            server: {
                host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
                port: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                    pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
                },
            },
            from: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_FROM,
            maxAge: 10 * 60,
        })
    ],
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma)
})
```

error:

```
Module not found: Package path ./providers is not exported from package D:\nextautht\supa-vacation-start\supa-vacation-start\node_modules\next-auth (see exports field in D:\nextautht\supa-vacation-start\supa-vacation-start\node_modules\next-auth\package.json)
  1 | import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
> 2 | import { EmailProvider } from "next-auth/providers";
  3 | import nodemailer from "nodemailer"
  4 | import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
  5 | import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
```

Comment: `EmmailProvider` is meant to be imported from `next-auth/providers/email`. See https://next-auth.js.org/providers/email.

Answer (score 0):

`EmailProvider` is not being imported from `next-auth/providers`
it works if we import it from `next-auth/providers/email` instead.
I think this is because export in the `nodemodules/nextauth/package.json` exports providers in form of `/providers/*`.